# MFC dialog in ATL activeX control does not have visual style

Tags: c++, mfc

In our project, we have a application which is used to host controls. For some reason, the application can not insert manifest for Microsoft Common Control v6.0.

We create a new activeX control using ATL. and #defined ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED in stdafx.h. We have also add manifest for comCtl32.dll(v6.0). The buttons or combobox that created by ATL or Win32 in this control could show with visual style.

But, if the controls are created by MFC, e.g. CButton::Create,  they will be shown without visual style. I've tried many solutions, including using ActiveContext API. But, this issue still cannot be fixed.

Our complier is VS2013. 
Can anyone helped about this?

Comment: This issue only happens when the host application and activeX control are both build with release configuration.

Comment: Is this Unicode or MBCS? By default the common control 6 manifest that gets generated in `stdafx.h` is `#ifdef`'ed for Unicode builds only.

Comment: It's built with UNICODE character set.  What is confusing me is that why ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED does not work for MFC dialog. But it works for dialog created by ATL.

Comment: @Bobby, did you get a resolution for this?

Comment: Appears as if you asked the same question http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/a882da33-7232-48d0-9d3c-12914f458ffa?category=vcgeneral